# Laravel 6. Как выводить одновременно категории и его родителя?

Tags: laravel

Как выводить одновременно категории и его родителя из таблиц?
**В моделе:**

```
public function bookCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(BookCategory::class,'book_category_id','id')
       //->leftJoin('books_categories','books_categories.id','=','books_categories.parent_id') -не работает
            ->select(['id','parent_id','title']);

}
```

**Сам запрос на контроллере:**

```
            $posts = BookPost::with('user', 'bookCategory')->latest()->get();
```

Comment: какие ошибки? В примере вы и не выводите родитетеля. Родитель первой категории будет примерно: $posts[0]->bookCatogory;

Comment: Нет. Не выводит. SQL запрос примерно такой должен
`SELECT * FROM books_categories AS t1 
LEFT JOIN  books_categories t2 ON t2.id=t1.parent_id
WHERE t1.id=35`

Comment: @eem-kz: прошу прощения, но мне не совсем понятен Ваш вопрос. Не могли бы ли Вы конкретизировать его? Код какой модели представлен? какого контроллера? и что значит: "выводить одновременно категории и его родителя из таблиц"?

Comment: Есть две таблицы: первый из них древовидный  `books_categories ` с полями `id,parent_id,title`. Второй: `books` c полями `book_name, book_category_id`. По умолчанию это код работает, выводить ссылающий категорию. Проблема в том, что если ` book_category_id` ссылается на подкатегорию  необходимо выводить родительскую категорию. Например; Электроника->Apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попытаюсь ответить. Насколько я понял, Вам необходимо получить цепочку родителей для категории.

Если вложенность подкатегорий неограничена, то Вам нужны рекурсивные отношения. С их помощью можно получить дочерние подкатегории.

Вот [здесь](https://laravel.demiart.ru/recursive-hasmany-relationship-with-unlimited-subcategories/) хорошая статья.

Если вложенность категорий ограничена (всего два уровня вложенности Category->Subcategory), то можно обойтись отношением parent() в модели:

```
/**
 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function parent(): belongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(__CLASS__, 'parent_id');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Необходимо было только дописать еще одно отношения через `with()`